# Local Services Ads API Python - No Data

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I do the oauth flow and then run the following code, but I'm getting no data; I've confirmed the `manager_customer_id` does in fact exist. Any suggestions of why? Thanks!

```
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords"]  

# Create an instance of InstalledAppFlow
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config(
    {
        "web": {
            "client_id": client_id,
            "client_secret": client_secret,
            "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
        }
    }, 
    scopes=scopes
)

# Choose a consistent port number for the OAuth callback
# Make sure this port is the same as the one set in your Google Cloud Console redirect URI
#credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

print(f"Running local server for authentication on port {consistent_port}...")

# Run the flow to get the credentials
credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=consistent_port)

print("Authentication successful. Obtained credentials.")

# Use credentials to create a session
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.token}'})

print("Session created. Preparing API request...")

# Your API request code goes here
url = "https://localservices.googleapis.com/v1/accountReports:search"


params = {
    "query": "manager_customer_id:xxxxx",
  #  "startDate.month": "12",
  #  "startDate.day": "1",
  #  "startDate.year": "2023",
  #  "endDate.month": "12",
  #  "endDate.day": "31",
 #   "endDate.year": "2023",
   # "pageSize": "500",
}

# Send the GET request using the OAuth session
response = session.get(url, params=params)


# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Successfully received API response.")
    data = response.json()
    print("Data:", data)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve data. Status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.text)
```